# Why isn't my knockout observable property, and boud input field being updated?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an object with observable properties.

```
this.userToAdd = {
        ID: ko.observable(""),
        FirstName: ko.observable(""),
        LastName: ko.observable(""),
        Active: ko.observable(""),
        Email: ko.observable(""),
        Roles: ko.observableArray([])
    };
```

I attempt to update the object when a button is clicked

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {

    var itemToUpdate = ko.dataFor(this);

    if (itemToUpdate.ID !== undefined) {
        //update observable
        vm.userToAdd.ID = itemToUpdate.ID;
        vm.userToAdd.FirstName = itemToUpdate.FirstName;
        vm.userToAdd.LastName = itemToUpdate.LastName;
        vm.userToAdd.Email = itemToUpdate.Email;
        vm.userToAdd.Active = itemToUpdate.Active;
        vm.userToAdd.Roles = itemToUpdate.Roles;
        //update form, and there must be a better way
        $('input[name="ID"]').val(itemToUpdate.ID);
        $('input[name="FirstName"]').val(itemToUpdate.FirstName);
        $('input[name="LastName"]').val(itemToUpdate.LastName);
        $('input[name="Email"]').val(itemToUpdate.Email);
        $('input[name="Active"]').val(itemToUpdate.Active);      
    }
});
```

It runs because I see the input fields being updated with the values I would expect, but the model is not updated. What am I doing wrong? Also, I had to use

```
$('input[name="ID"]').val(itemToUpdate.ID);
```

to update the input field

```
<input name="ID" type="text" placeholder="ID" data-bind="value: ID, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

because the value of the input field would not update even when the observable property was updated. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ko.observable` call returns a function. To set its value you need to call it with the new value as the argument:

```
vm.userToAdd.ID(itemToUpdate.ID);
vm.userToAdd.FirstName(itemToUpdate.FirstName);
vm.userToAdd.LastName(itemToUpdate.LastName);
vm.userToAdd.Email(itemToUpdate.Email);
vm.userToAdd.Active(itemToUpdate.Active);
vm.userToAdd.Roles(itemToUpdate.Roles);
```

For further reading: [Reading and writing observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> To **write** a new value to the observable, call the observable and pass
>   the new value as a parameter. For example, calling
>   `myViewModel.personName('Mary')` will change the name value to 'Mary'.